# How to deploy simple streamlit app in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, streamlit

I was successfully able to deploy flask app in Elastic Beanstalk but, Please tell me how to deploy streamlit app.

Eg:-
app.py has below code

```
import streamlit as st
def main():
  st.write("Launching a streamlit app")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

also I created one more file naming application.py with below code:

```
import os
os.system("streamlit run app.py")
```

Now along with requirement.txt with all the dependancy packages I zipped and tried to deploy in Elastic Beanstalk environment(Python 3.9 Platform), For flask app it worked but streamlit app doesn't work. Please help me. I **do not want to dockerize** and then deploy it.